# How to set Azure Service Bus timeout

Tags: node.js, azure, azureservicebus

I am using Azure Service Bus SDK of node.js. I am getting a `CONNECTIONTIMEDOUT` error in sendQueueMessage. I would like to extend the timeout period, but where can I configure it. Can any one please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the timeout by using MessagingFactorySettings:

```
    Uri serviceBusUri = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", "[serviceNamespace]", string.Empty);

    MessagingFactorySettings factorySettings = new MessagingFactorySettings()
    {
        TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider("[keyName]", "[sharedAccessKey]"),
        OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
    };

    MessagingFactory messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.Create(serviceBusUri, factorySettings);
    QueueClient Client = messagingFactory.CreateQueueClient("[QueueName]");
```

Similar to Azure SDK in .NET, Azure SDK for node.js does not have MessagingFactorySettings Class with OpertaionsTimeout property.

We can achieve the same by REST API call. All we need to do is send the Http Request (using POST verb) to the topic and mention timeout: 
https://{namespace}.{appfabric.windows.net}/{topicname}//messages?timeout=60

Refer to below documents for reference -

[azure-servicebus-topic-using-rest-api](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/applisec/2012/03/08/azure-servicebus-topic-using-rest-api-part-2/)

[peek-lock-message-non-destructive-read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/peek-lock-message-non-destructive-read)

Comment: Thank you for answering．
Is this also possible with node.js?

Comment: @田中太郎, were you able to find if it is possible with node.js?